# Adding Circular Image to Top-Center of Square Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate what you see on this website: http://midwc.net/, where there are four divs with circular images above the titles ("Container Catalog", "Custom Containers", "You First", "Blog"). You can see that the circles are perfectly centered horizontally and vertically (across the top border of the square).

Unfortunately my attempt is pretty far off:

[image]

First of all, you can see that there's space between the images and their borders - I need to get rid of that. The border should be directly around the image.

Second, the circle images are up and to the left of where they should be, but I'm wondering what the best way to fix this is without using magjc numbers, since they won't work when the page resizes.

Here's a JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cwzm8cbj/2/

HTML:

```
<div class = "container-1">
<div class = "bs-container">
    <div class = "circle-wrapper">
        <img class = "circle" src = "http://thebullshitcollection/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Bullshit_Drawing.png"/>
    </div>
    <h3>BULLSHIT DRAWINGS</h3>
    <p>Black and white, colored pencil drawings of actual bullshit.</p>
    <div class="center-button">
    <a href="#" class="more-bs-a">
        <button class="more-bs">More Bullshit</button>
    </a>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class = "bs-container">
    <div class = "circle-wrapper">
        <img class = "circle" src = "http://thebullshitcollection/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Bullshit_Photograph.png"/>
    </div>
    <h3>BULLSHIT PHOTOGRAPHY</h3>
    <p>Black and white, color photographs in a wide variety of sizes.
    </p>
    <div class="center-button">
    <a href="#" class="more-bs-a">
        <button class="more-bs">More Bullshit</button>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class = "bs-container">
    <div class = "circle-wrapper">
        <img class = "circle" src = "http://thebullshitcollection/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Bullshit_Tutorial.png"/>
    </div>
    <h3>BULLSHIT TUTORIALS</h3>
    <p>Free, online tutorials to help you draw your own bullshit.</p>
    <div class="center-button">
    <a href="#" class="more-bs-a">
        <button class="more-bs">Subscribe</button>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-1 {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.bs-container {
border: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
margin-right: 1.8%;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
height: 220px;
width: 360px;
/*gradient background developed here: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,f5f0dd+100 */
background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,240,221,1) 100%); 
/* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(245,240,221,1) 100%); 
/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(245,240,221,1) 100%); 
/* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f5f0dd',GradientType=0 ); 
/* IE6-9 */
}

.bs-container h3 {
color: #BCBEC0;
text-align: center;
font-family: PT Sans Narrow;
font-size: 23px;
}

.bs-container p {
font-size: 18px;
font-family: PT Sans Narrow;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.circle-wrapper {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
top: -50px;
width: 260px;
text-align: center;
}

.circle {
border: 5px solid #BCBEC0;
border-radius: 50%; 
}

.more-bs {
text-align: center;
font-family: Beautiful ES;
color: white;
background-color: #543D2B;
border: 4px solid #000000;
height: 48px;
font-size: 33px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.more-bs:hover {
color: #9B6A49;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.more-bs-a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.more-bs-a:hover {
color: #9B6A49;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.center-button {
text-align: center;
}

.container, .container-1 {
width: 80.9%;
padding: 0px 5% 0 10%;
}
```

How can I cause these images to always be centered at the top of the div no matter the page size? Do I need JavaScript?

Thanks

**EDIT**: after adding `position: relative` to the `.bs-container` class:

[image]

**EDIT 2**: after applying these styles to `.circle-wrapper`:

[image]

This gets me almost there - now I just need the images to appear on top of the containers, like they're on a new, separate layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to `.bs-container`

`overflow: visible !important;` and `position: relative;`

And update `.circle-wrapper` to look like this

```
.circle-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: -8%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 260px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
}
```

I can't test with your images because they aren't loading though. You could play with the top and left values for `.circle-wrapper`

Comment: sorry about that - let me create a new JS fiddle real quick with paths that link to the images via imgur.

Comment: Okay see if this works: https://jsfiddle.net/cwzm8cbj/2/ (also edited the link up above in the post)

Comment: Yeah this is getting me really close: http://i.imgur.com/3RMvICz.png. After changing `top:` to `0%`, I was able to center it across the top border. Now I just need to get rid of the space between the circular image and its border and push down the rest of the content with margins.

Comment: yeah, that link works. And my answer still works with that. I just changed the top value for the .circle-wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! You fixed my main problem: http://i.imgur.com/Q7vKaOQ.png. Now I'm just trying to get rid of the space between the circular images and their borders. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: The images you're using have that space included in the image. You'll need new images without those transparent pixels.

Comment: Yes they do. If you inspect the img element with chrome and hover on the link, you'll see a preview of the image. You can see the transparent pixels because they are show with squares. You can't see the transparent pixels with that preview in your mac.

Comment: I guess I'm not looking at the same thing? http://imgur.com/a/xyslY Also if I give the `.circle` class a white background, that gets rid of the transparency: http://i.imgur.com/f7fUa0p.png Maybe the image has an invisible, transparent radius that's extending outside of itself, but I don't know how to fix that in illustrator/photoshop....that would be a question for SO Graphic Design.

Answer (score 2):

Its all wrong . Wrap each ( image + heading + its info ) in a seperate `div`

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  background: red;
  border: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>image</h3>
  <h1>this is heading</h1>
  <h2>this is info</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>image</h3>
  <h1>this is heading</h1>
  <h2>this is info</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>image</h3>
  <h1>this is heading</h1>
  <h2>this is info</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>image</h3>
  <h1>this is heading</h1>
  <h2>this is info</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add position:relative to .bs-container 
this will absolutely position the circle-wrapper within it instead of the

Comment: That seems to be helping, what can I do to the circle wrapper class to center the image and place it above the top border of the `.bs-container`? Please see the edit above for how it looks after adding `position:relative`.